# porting pmwiki-pages to a different server

Tags: wiki, pmwiki

We have a Website with many pages based on pmwiki.
Now we have to move everything to a different server.

As the system administrators have already made our pages unavailable (without telling us!), we can only access our stuff via sftp.

What is the easiest way to port our pmwiki pages?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

PmWiki stores all the pages in the `wiki.d` directory, and you can simply copy the files. If you have any customisations (recipes) you may want to copy them (`cookbook`, `pub` and `local` directories), but you may need to edit the local config to match the new server. Finally, if you have uploads then you'll want to copy them too. You may also choose to copy the PmWiki installation too (unless you want to upgrade).

The PmWiki [Backup and Restore](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/BackupAndRestore) page covers the concepts, you can consider it a backup from one server and restore to another.